# Add Years to existing datetime column to create a 2nd datetime column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, dateadd

I have a column in a SQL Server table with 1,000 rows populated with various `datetimes`. It's called `StartTime` and its data type is `datetime2(7)`.

I want to add a second column called `NewStartTime` that's 3 years out from the existing `datetime`.

For example, if row 1 value for `StartTime` is 2018-10-01 07:20:00.0000,
I want the row 1 value for `NewStartTime` to be 2021-10-01 07:20:00.0000.

I've tried a number of the `DATEADD` functions (with and without `LEFT`) but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: `DATEADD` is the right function to use. `LEFT` is a string function, there is no reason to use it here. Please show your attempt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

would go yet with [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
select StartTime
  , dateadd(year, 3, StartTime) as NewStartTime 
 from LNVTable;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cbeac/18)

Answer (score 3):

`Select StartTime, DATEADD(YEAR,3, StartTime) as NewStartTime  FROM MYTABLE;`